# Generate a function based upon name data in a csv file opened in R

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe of variable names and weightings.

Example:

```
Names <- c("a","b","c")
Weightings <- c(1,2,3)
df <- cbind(Names,Weightings)
```

I need to generate a function from this data as such.

```
myfun <- function(x,data){
data[x,"a"]*1+data[x,"b"]*2+data[x,"c"]*3}
```

I have another dataframe named data where the column names match a, b, and c and I will apply myfun to this data over all rows.

The issue I have is that the size of the Names and Weightings vector can vary.  I could be working with 5 names and Weightings but I want it to generate the new function "myfun" as such.

```
Newnames <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
NewWeightings <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

myfun <- function(data){
data[x,"a"]*1+data[x,"b"]*2+data[x,"c"]*3+data[x,"d"]*4+data[x,"e"]*5}
```

Is there an easy way to automate the creation of this function so I could give someone the code, and a .csv file of column names and weightings and they could generate their new function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a strategy like this. We use a function to make a function

```
getMyFunction <- function(columns, weights)  {
    stopifnot(length(columns)==length(weights))
    function(x, data) {
        rowSums(data[x, columns] * weights)
    }
}
```

Basically the rowSums takes care of the addition, we specify a vector of columns all at once, and the default `*` is element-wise so that takes care of the weights.

Then we build a function like

```
Names <- c("a","b","c")
Weightings <- c(1,2,3)
myFun <- getMyFunction(Names, Weightings)
```

and we can use it with

```
dd<-data.frame(a=c(1,1), b=c(1,2), c=c(1,3))

myFun(1,dd)
# [1] 6
myFun(2,dd)
# [1] 13
myFun(1:2,dd)
# [1] 6 13
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works quite well.  I'll have to look into the code for the rowSums function.